# CollectionView reloadItems(at: ) calls didSet() in multiple cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uibutton

I'm working on an app that has a `UICollectionView` with an infinite scroll. Each cell has a like button. The problem is that the lower I scroll - the slower the like button changes its color when tapped on.

It can take up to 3 seconds between the `print("BEGIN")` and `print("END")` in my code. I also observed that `print(post)` gets called dozens of times and it prints dozens of posts that I haven't tapped the like button on. I want it to only call the `didSet` in the cell I'm updating.

Can someone please explain why it seems like it's calling didSet in multiple cells instead of just one cell I tapped on? Does it have something to do with that cells are being reused?

How would you fix this long delay problem? I would like the cell to update it's like button image to a selected one without such a long delay.

```
protocol HomePostCellDelegate {
    func didTapLike(for cell: HomePostCell)
}

class HomePostCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var delegate: HomePostCellDelegate?

    var post: Post? {
        didSet {
            print(post)
            likeButton.setImage(post?.isLiked == true ? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "like_selected").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate) : #imageLiteral(resourceName: "like_unselected").withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate), for: .normal)
            likeButton.tintColor = .white

           // ...
        }
    }

    lazy var likeButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "like_unselected").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(handleLike), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    @objc func handleLike() {
        NSLog("@objc func handleLike()")
        delegate?.didTapLike(for: self)
    }
    // ...
}

class HomeController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, HomePostCellDelegate {

    // ...

    func didTapLike(for cell: HomePostCell) {

        let generator = UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light)
        generator.impactOccurred()

        guard let indexPath = collectionView?.indexPath(for: cell) else { return }
        guard let post = cell.post else { return }

        cell.post.isLiked = !cell.post.isLiked

        if cell.post.isLiked {
            cell.post.numberOfLikes += 1
        } else {
            cell.post.numberOfLikes -= 1
        }

        print("BEGIN")
        self.collectionView?.reloadItems(at: [indexPath])
        print("END")
    }
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    if indexPath.item == self.presenter.posts.count - 5 && !presenter.isFinishedPaging && !presenter.isCurrentlyPaging  {

        presenter.isCurrentlyPaging = true

        presenter.paginatePosts(withSuccess: { [weak self] () in
            self?.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()
            self?.collectionView?.reloadData()
            self?.presenter.isCurrentlyPaging = false
        }) { [weak self] (errorMessage) in
            self?.presenter.isCurrentlyPaging = false
            print(errorMessage)
        }
    }

    if presenter.posts.count == 0 {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: errorCellId, for: indexPath) as! ErrorCell

        setUpErrorCellAnimation(cell: cell)

        return cell
    } else if presenter.posts[indexPath.item].id == nil {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: adCellId, for: indexPath) as! AdCell

        // some ad logic here
        // ...

        cell.contentView.addSubview(bannerView)

        return cell
    } else {

        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! HomePostCell
        cell.delegate = self

        if presenter.isAdmin && presenter.isInAdminView {
            cell.isInAdminView = true
        } else {
            cell.isInAdminView = false
        }

        cell.post = presenter.posts[safe: indexPath.item]

        return cell
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Stack trace when putting a breakpoint inside the `didSet` method:
[image]

Comment: What is your actual need? explain your need please

Comment: @JamilHasnineTamim Thanks, I edited my post. How would you fix this long delay problem? I would like the cell to update it's like button image to a selected one without such a long delay. I'm also trying to understand why my didSet method gets called almost a 100 times.

Comment: Show your `cellForItemAt` method.

Comment: BTW - if you want to know why `didSet` is being called so much, put a break point on the `print(post)` line and run your code. Look at what is calling `didSet` each time.

Comment: Look at the stack trace shown in the debugger.

Comment: Every call to `cell.post = presenter.posts[safe: indexPath.item]` in your `cellForItemAt` will result in the `didSet` in your cell class. That's normal and expected.

Comment: You need to remove that whole first `if` block from your `cellForItemAt`. `cellForItemAt` must only do one thing - create, setup and return one cell. That's it. NEVER call `reloadData` there. Don't adjust other views. Just return a cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That makes sense. @rmaddy